# Call stored procedures in a loop using PDO gives previous calls results

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, pdo

I am in a need to call a stored procedure in a loop by using PDO. This procedure return multiple rows (not by `OUT` param). The problem I am facing is that sequential call adds all the results from previous calls to the new result. Say, if a single call with specific param returns 20 rows, second call will return 40 rows, third one - 60, etc. Param can be different from call to call while the results will still stack. The code I am using:

```
public function call($proc, $params) {
    $this->query = 'CALL '.$proc.'(?);';

    $this->statement = $this->pdo->prepare($this->query);
    $this->statement->execute($params);

    $data = $this->statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $this->statement->nextRowset();
    $this->statement->closeCursor();

    return $data;
}
```

From my understanding, I have probably failed with freeing the resources and fetching entire data, however no data is available after `fetchAll`. Why am I getting results from previous calls?

Edit: here is a similar code of sproc used in application (`_type` is IN param):

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE _start_entry INT UNSIGNED;
    DECLARE _next_entry INT UNSIGNED;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tableT` AS (SELECT * FROM `table` LIMIT 0);

    SELECT `entry` FROM `table` WHERE `type` = _type LIMIT 1 INTO _start_entry;

    read_loop: LOOP
        INSERT INTO `tableT` (SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE entry = _start_entry);
        SELECT `next_entry` FROM `table` WHERE entry = _start_entry INTO _next_entry;
        SELECT _next_entry INTO _start_entry;
        IF _next_entry = 0 THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;
    END LOOP read_loop;

    SELECT * FROM `tableT`;
END
```

Comment: Is the rest of your application caching this data somewhere (i.e. is this data pushed into a result array inside this class?)

Comment: @EatPeanutButter nope. This method retrieves data and immideately returns it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that multiple calls were perfomed within the same session. This leads temporary table `tableT` to exist among all the calls and contain results from previous calls. Easy fix:

```
    [...]
    SELECT * FROM `tableT`;
    DROP TABLE `tableT`;  <-- this
END
```